# installing wxGTK-devel on CentOS 5.4

Tags: linux, centos, yum, rpm

I'm trying to install wxGTK-devel on CentOS and since it's not in the base repo I added RPMForge. But now I'm getting these broken dependencies. I don't want start tampering with separate rpms because I suspect it will make thing worse. I remember installing this package from RPMForge without a problem several months ago. Please, advise.

...

wxGTK-2.8.10-1.el4.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libgstreamer-0.8.so.1()(64bit) is needed by package wxGTK-2.8.10-1.el4.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
wxGTK-2.8.10-1.el4.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libgstgconf-0.8.so.0()(64bit) is needed by package wxGTK-2.8.10-1.el4.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
wxGTK-2.8.10-1.el4.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libgstinterfaces-0.8.so.0()(64bit) is needed by package wxGTK-2.8.10-1.el4.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: libgstreamer-0.8.so.1()(64bit) is needed by package wxGTK-2.8.10-1.el4.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: libgstinterfaces-0.8.so.0()(64bit) is needed by package wxGTK-2.8.10-1.el4.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: libgstgconf-0.8.so.0()(64bit) is needed by package wxGTK-2.8.10-1.el4.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added the repository for EL4. CentOS 5 is EL5.

Comment: I copied the wrong lines from Installing RPMforge article. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I cant post comments yet. so please consider the following:

- the compilation is looking for missing libraries, which might not be placed in your $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
- the libraries called are 64 bits, it might be a GTK for 64bits platform while yours is 32 (just thinking out loud)
- the RPMs are mentioning x86 platform, is yours x86 or AMD?

I hope this can help